# xquery iterating over values

Tags: xml, xquery

Here is my xml:

```
<book asin="0201100886" created="128135928" lastLookupTime="128135928"> 
  <uuid>BA57A934-6CDC-11D9-830B-000393D3DE16</uuid> 
  <title>Compilers</title> 
  <authors> 
<author>Alfred V. Aho</author> 
<author>Ravi Sethi</author> 
<author>Jeffrey D. Ullman</author> 
  </authors> 
</book>
```

I want to know all the books who were co-authored by Jeffrey D. Ullman. That means he cant be the first author in the list. So my xQuery so far is:

```
xquery version "1.0";
for $book in doc("library.xml")/library/items/book
where not($book/authors/author = "Jeffrey D. Ullman")
return
<name>{data($book/authors/author)}</name>
```

That gives me all the books he hasnt authored but how do I go over the rest of the authors besides doing author[2] author[3] to see if he co authored it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/library/items/book[authors/subsequence(author, 2) = "Jeffrey D. Ullman"]
```

Comment: What if he is the third author? Is there anyway not to hard code it?

Comment: @zach: `fn:subsequence($seq,$start)` means the subsequence starting by `$start` position. It's the same as `/library/items/book[authors/author[position()!=1] = "Jeffrey D. Ullman"]`